# RestKit managed object created on GET returns false for bool always

Tags: ios, core-data, restkit, restkit-0.20

I am doing a GET call with rest kit with an entity mapping which has a boolean isPrimary. The call is successful and the mapping array also has the correct value for isPrimary when i nslog it. But when i retrieve the entity form core data using a simple fetch request with out any predicate the value is always "false". All non boolean vars are correct. Any help is much appreciated.cheers

The Header:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
#import "StringBase.h"

@class MaterialPlantRel, PriceList, SalesOrder;

@interface Currency : StringBase

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * baseCurrency;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) SalesOrder *billingCurrencyInv;
@property (nonatomic, retain) PriceList *currencyTOInv;
@property (nonatomic, retain) MaterialPlantRel *ledgerCostCurrencyInv;
@property (nonatomic, retain) SalesOrder *paymentCurrencyInv;
@property (nonatomic, retain) MaterialPlantRel *replacementCostCurrencyInv;

// Returns a dictionary representation of the
// object with var keys and values;
-(NSDictionary*) getDictionaryRepresentation;

/** Override to map the values to object **/
-(void) setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)keyedValues;

@end
```

output JSON on success:

```
        Sucess Currency (
        "<Currency: 0xda70f30> (entity: Currency; id: 0xb07e980 <x- coredata://C145A537-         5E8B-4E4E-95C1-BDFF10C84B05/Currency/p151> ; data: {\n    active = 1;\n    baseCurrency =    1;\n    billingCurrencyInv = nil;\n    code = BRL;\n    createdBy = nil;\n    currencyTOInv = nil;\n    ledgerCostCurrencyInv = nil;\n    modifiedBy = nil;\n    name = \"Brazilian Riaz\";\n    paymentCurrencyInv = nil;\n    replacementCostCurrencyInv = nil;\n    version = 1;\n})",
       "<Currency: 0xda6c0b0> (entity: Currency; id: 0xb07d000 <x-coredata://C145A537-5E8B-4E4E-95C1-BDFF10C84B05/Currency/p152> ; data: {\n    active = 1;\n    baseCurrency = 0;\n    billingCurrencyInv = nil;\n    code = USD;\n    createdBy = nil;\n    currencyTOInv = nil;\n    ledgerCostCurrencyInv = nil;\n    modifiedBy = nil;\n    name = \"US Dollars\";\n      paymentCurrencyInv = nil;\n    replacementCostCurrencyInv = nil;\n    version = 1;\n})"
        )

CoreData fetch : 

        NSFetchRequest* fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest        fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Currency"];
       // get the managed object context
       NSManagedObjectContext* l_MOC = [[[RestKitConfig ConfigManager] AppDelegateSales] managedObjectContext];
       // setup entity description
       NSEntityDescription* entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription
                                              entityForName:@"Currency"
                                              inManagedObjectContext:l_MOC];
       // fetch the request
      [fetchRequest setEntity:entityDescription];

    // Set example predicate and sort orderings...
    NSError* error;
    NSArray* array = [l_MOC executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

    if ([array count] > 0)
    {
        // copy of the retrieved data
        self.data = [array copy];
#ifdef _DEBUG
        NSLog(@"Currency Data retrieved : %i Objects",[array count]);
        for (int i = 0; i < [array count]; i++)
        {
            Currency* l_currency = [array objectAtIndex:i];
            NSLog(@"base currency -> %@",l_currency.baseCurrency);
        }
#endif

Output : 
2014-05-28 13:07:03.187 Sales[2110:1003] base currency -> 0
2014-05-28 13:07:03.187 Sales[2110:1003] base currency -> 0
```

Comment: Is it transient? Show your test code. Show the managed object class header.

Comment: @wain not sure what you mean by transient.I've posted the code either way.

Comment: Transient (as opposed to persistent) is a flag you set on the attribute in the data model. And I don't see `isPrimary` anywhere in the code you added?!?

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to mention that I cannot show the isPrimary code. This is just a dummy that has the same issue. @wain I checked for the transient flag, it is set to optional. tested with indexed option but to no avail.

Comment: the boolean is baseCurrency. sorry for the trouble. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is this fetch code running on the main thread? The code looks generally ok. What do you see if you log the whole object, both in the success block and in your fetch results?

Comment: Thanks a lot wain. The issue was i was calling the GET request in an async thread. When called on the main thread it works fine. But i still don't understand why the rest of the data is correct and only this is currupted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using a managed object context in a multi-threaded environment you need to be careful to use the context only on the intended thread. The main thread has a specific context and each background thread must have a new context created for it. If you use the wrong context for a thread (or access a private queue context without using the private queue) then you will see strange issues and / or exceptions. The type of issues you will see depend on what is already saved into the context and what operations you try to perform, but it will generally never be correct.

So, take care to use only the appropriate context and that the relationships between contexts ensure that newly saved data is notified and updated where you need it.